# HTTPS not working on CentOS Apache 2.4

Tags: centos, ssl, apache-httpd

I have created a key and self-signed certificate and moved them to `/etc/httpd/conf/`

My `ssl.conf` is here: http://pastebin.com/gsQbKY67

The `ssl_module (shared)` is there when I try `httpd -M`

Output from `netstat -tulpn | grep 443` : `tcp6 0 0 :::443 :::* LISTEN 2640/httpd`

There's nothing in the `/var/log/httpd/error_log / ssl_error_log` files.

When I try `https://<my-server-ip>/secure` I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 1):

as you can notice from:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 443 : tcp6 0 0 :::443 :::* LISTEN 2640/httpd
```

the port 443 is listening on tcp6, which translated you have Ipv6 and not Ipv4.

Is your system configured with IPv4 or 6?

Pls make sure your configuration is using the proper IP protocol and you will that you wont have issues anymore....

Comment: This is the output from `ifconfig | grep inet6` : `inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb4:ed8e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link> inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>`. I presume that means it's configured with IPv6?

Comment: Nope, it means your system is running both Ipv4/6 and the apache is automatically binds on ipv6 for some reason. you need to check the main httpd.conf and see what is the IP that apache is listening to.

Comment: is that the reason that it's not working? here is my `httpd.conf` http://pastebin.com/Hk0u85nb what do I need to look for? Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes, you need to change Listen 80 to Listen 0.0.0.0:80. pls refer to apache official guide if you don't know what you are dealing with: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html